# Ubuntu lsblk drive size

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, hard-disk, zfs, lsblk

I am setting up a ZFS NAS using Ubuntu 18 with 8 hard drives for storage. When I use `sudo lsblk -P` to check what the drive names are, I only see `sdb-sdh`. I know this is because it will skip over the drives that are a size 0. I did `sudo lsblk -Pa` and then I see `sda`, but `SIZE=""`. My question is, does `SIZE=""` mean that this drive is bad and needs to be replaced, or is there something else that needs to be done with this drive that I am not aware of? Thank you for your help.

**Image of `lsblk -Pa`**

[image]

**Update**
After typing in `sudo smartctl -iHAf brief -l error -l xerror /dev/sda` this is the output:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-52-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              DKS2D-H3R0SS
Revision:             4F09
User Capacity:        2,983,000,009,600 bytes [2.98 TB]
Logical block size:   520 bytes
Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm
Form Factor:          3.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c50056efa9cf
Serial number:        Z2987NX20000C3515M22
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Sun Jun 23 13:46:00 2019 UTC
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     46 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        68 C

Manufactured in week 29 of year 2013
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  191
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  191
Elements in grown defect list: 1

Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 815387184
  Blocks received from initiator = 128354709
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 0
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 3123587
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 0

Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 16529.18
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 47

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:   1509905219        0         0  1509905219          0        424.001           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0         66.846           0
verify:   306677        0         0    306677          0          0.000           0

Non-medium error count:       89


[GLTSD (Global Logging Target Save Disable) set. Enable Save with '-S on']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it might well mean the drive is bad. Some disk drives indicate that they are failing their internal diagnostics by reporting their size as zero, others may respond to commands with a  "no media inserted" error code in the same situation.

You probably should check the SMART status of the disk: `smartctl -iHAf brief -l error -l xerror /dev/sda` should output a concise report of the most important SMART disk health information.

Also, you might want to look at the output of `dmesg -H` for error messages.

Comment: Thank your for your advice, I ran the `smartctl` check you mentioned, and I have updated my question with the output of that report. It says status is `OK`. Could there be other indications that would show the drive is bad? If it is not bad, is there a way to get it to be use able? I can't even write zeros using `dd` to it.

Comment: I also looked at the output of `dmesg -H` but I didn't see any errors